# Normalizing table LIMIT issue

Tags: mysql, sql, normalization, database-normalization

I have 3 tables `song`, `author`, `song_author`.

Connection is `song 1--* song_author 1--* author`

I use a query like

```
SELECT *
FROM song
LEFT JOIN song_author ON s_id = sa_song
LEFT JOIN author ON sa_author = a_id
```

For the given example that would result in 3 rows:

```
John - How beautiful it is
John - Awesome
George - Awesome
```

and I am populating my objects like that so it's fine.

However, I want to add a `LIMIT` clause, but because it is returning several rows for just one song a `LIMIT 10` doesn't always show 10 songs.

The other possibility I know is print all songs and then inside take a second query, but that would result in `O(n)` which I'd like to avoid.

```
author:
+------+--------+
| a_id | a_name |
+------+--------+
|    1 | John   |
|    2 | George |
+------+--------+

song:
+------+---------------------+
| s_id |       s_name        |
+------+---------------------+
|    1 | How beautiful it is |
|    2 | Awesome             |
+------+---------------------+

song_author:
+-----------+---------+
| sa_author | sa_song |
+-----------+---------+
|         1 |       1 |
|         1 |       2 |
|         2 |       2 |
+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: I think your associations are wrong. Instead of `song *--1 song_author *--1 author`, you really have `song 1--* song_author *--1 author`, right?

A song can have many authors (thru song_author), and an author can have many songs (thru song_author).

Comment: @omgitsfletch yeah, I will fix that, ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT *
    FROM song
    LIMIT 10) r
LEFT JOIN song_author ON r.s_id = sa_song
LEFT JOIN author ON sa_author = a_id
```

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, your goal is what, exactly? It seems like you want to grab a set amount of songs at one time (10 in the example), and all related authors for said songs. However, if multiple of those [song, author] record tuples represented the same song, you'd end up with 10 records, but less than 10 actual songs.

I like Marcin's approach, but if you want to avoid sub-queries and temporary tables, you can instead use a feature built into MySQL: `GROUP_CONCAT()`

```
SELECT
    s_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a_name SEPARATOR '|')
FROM
    song
LEFT JOIN
    song_author ON sa_song = s_id
LEFT JOIN
    author ON a_id = sa_author
GROUP BY
    s_name
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: This isn't the most efficient approach in the world, however. You're sacrificing some speed for the sake of data presentation, which might not be acceptable depending on the scale of data in your system.

If you needed something more efficient, I'd instead avoid this approach, do a dependent subquery such as the kind Marcin suggested, and combine your artists in an actual programming language after querying.